# Have <li> inside navigation <li> in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists

How to add

element in navigation

to look like this

[image]

For now i have this, i dont need the styling of lines etc, only focus on langauge selector to be on top of other. Here is what i have for now

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        <li>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Misson statement</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Working jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/y9RgH/

Comment: Please put them in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9RgH/1/ - this is what you meant?

Comment: Why to add line height??